# Swift iOS Memory Leak Indicated XCode8 when Derived from NSObject

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, nsobject

Xcode8 is showing a memory leak in instruments and the memory graph. I have narrowed it down to this: deriving from NSObject produces a leak indication. I have no idea why.

I need an NSObject to later use the @objc directive.

The Test instance stored in the mDict Dictionary is indicated as a leak in Xcode.

This is running as an iOS Single-View-Application project in the iPhone5s Simulator running iOS10.0

```
import Foundation

class Test: NSObject  // <-- derived from NSObject produces leak indication below
{
    static var cTest: Test! = nil
    var mDict: [String : Test] = Dictionary<String, Test>()

    static func test() -> Void {
        cTest = Test()
        cTest.mDict["test"] = Test() // <-- alleged leak
    }
}

class Test  // <-- NOT derived from NSObject, NO leak indication
{
    static var cTest: Test! = nil
    var mDict: [String : Test] = Dictionary<String, Test>()

    static func test() -> Void {
        cTest = Test()
        cTest.mDict["test"] = Test() // <-- NO leak
    }
}

// from AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
// ...
    Test.test()
// ...
```

Comment: Trying declaring mDict as `weak var` in the `NSObject` example. I suspect a strong memory cycle is occurring where mDict is not being de-allocated after use.

Comment: Thanks @Danoram. When I try that I get 'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not 'Dictionary<String, Test>'. Also, I'd like mDict to stick around, i.e. not be weak but it is worth a try to gather clues. The funny thing is, when the leak is indicated, I can later set cTest to nil and all is dealloc-ed. Nothing leaked. Hmmm...

Comment: Fascinating. That might be your best option in terms of solving the leak

Answer (score 0):

Memory gestion in swift is a little bit different from the objective c's for the classes. Than doing `class Test: NSObject` you maybe miss this characteristics.
If you try `class Test: AnyObject` you have to solve your issue.

Or try to use `deinit` every moment you have done with it

```
class Test: NSObject  // <-- using deinit
{
   static var cTest: Test! = nil
   var mDict: [String : Test] = Dictionary<String, Test>()

   static func test() -> Void {
      cTest = Test()
      cTest.mDict["test"] = Test() // <-- alleged leak
   }

   deinit {

   }
}
```

But the best practice declare it as `weak` variable, like `weak var test: Test?` in your case

Comment: Thank you @Achron. Yes. the leak indicator is gone  *but* I need to inherit from NSObject to use @@objc. This is not possible when you inherit from AnyObject. Other ideas/solutions?

Comment: Maybe if you'll use `deinit` on object you will solve. If still not working try to use `init` as well.

Comment: Thank you @Achron. Unfortunately init() and deist did not help. In my example deinit never gets called. The leak is still indicated.

Comment: Just added the line into answer. Try to declare the variable as `weak`

Comment: Thank you @Achron. You mean the var mDict as weak var mDict, right? A previous poster mentioned that as well. Unfortunately it produces a compiler error. (See above.) Please let me know if understood you correctly and if so, what would be the correct code syntax?

Comment: No, i mean class it self. Like mentioned in my answer, when you start to use your class it should be `weak` and optional, `weak var test: Test?".

Comment: Thank you @Achron. I wish I could move this to a chat. I do not 'use' the instance. I am illustrating the behavior as brief as possible. The only Test instance is the static variable cTest. When I make this weak, `static weak var cTest: Test! = nil` it crashes since it is immediately dealloc-ed before its mDict is referenced and filled. Further, the code works flawlessly (no leaks) if Test is not derived from NSObject.

Comment: for the object class should be `weak var cTest: Test? = nil` (optional, not forced unwrapping). 'static` maybe can cause problems

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be fixed in Xcode release version 8.2 (8C38). A leak is no longer indicated.

Comment: I still see a problem, actually.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially the same thing as the original question. Here is my test code that has a similar problem. YMMV. Running on iPad air iOS 10.1 Version 8.2 (8C38)

```
import UIKit

class Thing {}

class Test: NSObject
{
    static let shared = Test()
    var dictionary: [String: Thing] = [:]

    func method() {
        dictionary = ["value": Thing()]
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Test.shared.method()
        print("Leaky leaky... click on the memory visualizer to see issues.")
    }
}
```

If you remove NSObject, the problem goes away. I filed a radar for what its worth.

I don't see the problem if I run as a command line tool and use the command line `leaks` command to inspect.